# Using a value to fire Jcombobox actionlistener instead of getselectedindex?

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jcombobox

here is the Jcombobox it has two items name and id

```
   public void ComboItem() {

chooser.removeAllItems();
chooser.addItem("Please Select...");
try {   

         String sql="select * from Patients_Details";
         pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
         rs=pst.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            String id = rs.getString("Patient_ID"); // Get the Id
            String name = rs.getString("Name"); // Get the Name 

            ComboItem comboItem = new ComboItem(id, name); // Create a new ComboItem
            chooser.addItem(comboItem); // Put it into the ComboBox
            String tmp=comboItem.getid();
        }


    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        System.out.println(sqle);
    }
```

Jcombobox ActionListener code

```
private void chooserPopupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(javax.swing.event.PopupMenuEvent evt) {                                                     
    Object selectedValue = chooser.getSelectedIndex();

    try{


      String sql="select * from Patients_Details where Patient_ID=? ";
      pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
      pst.setObject(1, selectedValue);
      rs=pst.executeQuery();
      if(rs.next()){

      String add1=rs.getString("Patient_ID");
      txtpatientid.setText(add1);
      String add2=rs.getString("Name");
      txtname.setText(add2);
      String add3=rs.getString("Age");
      txtage.setText(add3);
      String add4=rs.getString("Gender");
      txtgender.setText(add4);
      String add7=rs.getString("Date");
      txtdate.setText(add7);

       }

  }

  catch(Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e ); 
  }
}
```

My question is:
 How can I use the id as a value to fire JCombobox listener instead of getSelectedindex Any help  will be appreciated.

Comment: You had [previously](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16374495/230513)[asked](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16374495/1) asked about "previous and next button"; is that still of interest?

Answer (score 1):

Use `getSelectedItem()` to obtain a reference to the currently selected `ComboItem`, and it's `id`; use `getSelectedIndex()` to obtain it's index.

Because `setSelectedIndex()` fires the combo's `ActionListener`, navigational controls such as <kbd>⊲Prev</kbd> and <kbd>Next⊳</kbd> buttons can delegate to the combo, as shown [here](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/googleolympiad):

- Obtain the `index` from `getSelectedIndex()`.
- Increment or decrement the `index`.
- Perform a range check on the `index`.
- Delegate the selection to the combo via `setSelectedIndex(index)`.

A particular implementation of `ComboBoxModel`, such as `DefaultComboBoxModel`, can be searched using iteration:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dcbm.getSize(); i++) {
    ComboItem item = (ComboItem) dcbm.getElementAt(i);
    // check item
}
```